# Difference between prime counting functions(Resolved)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Good afternoon everyone! Given $N$ and $k$ are natural numbers, with $k<N$, and $\pi(x)$ counts the number of primes less than x or equal to x(edited), can someone give me some tips for simplifying(perhaps removing the dependency on N entirely) the following expression. $\pi(N) - \pi(N-k)$, it seems like it should be simpler than I'm making it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You think that function is independent of $N$?

Comment: It might help you if you did some numerical experimentation.  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5Bprimepi%5Bn%5D-primepi%5Bn-20%5D%2C%7Bn%2C+21%2C+500%7D%5D) is well able to compute that function, at least for modest $N, k$.

Comment: The difference is exactly the number of primes in the interval $(N-k,N]$, which certainly depends on the particular interval (try different numerical values to check).

Comment: Good point. I know its the number of primes on that interval :).

Comment: I don't think it's independent, but perhaps the lower bound is?

Comment: I appreciate it!

Comment: @JohnEaton The best possible lower bound (that doesn't depend on $N$) for this quantity is precisely $0$.  You can always find $k$ consecutive composites, no matter how large $k$ is.

Comment: Note, the modern convention for $\pi(x)$ is that it counts the number of primes less than **or equal to** $x$. (I think some older books use the strictly less than definition, for which $\pi(2)=0$.)

Comment: Thank you @ErickWong

Comment: Good point @BarryCipra, that is what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the prime number theorem $\pi(n) \approx x / \log n$, and thus
$$ \pi(N + k) - \pi(N) \approx \frac{N+k}{\log(N + k)} - \frac{N}{\log N},$$
and if $N$ is much larger than $k$ then this is well-approximated by
$$ \frac{N + k}{\log N} - \frac{N}{\log N} = \frac{k}{\log N}.$$

I'll note that this is the same as you would get from the prime number theorem probability statement that the probability that a random integer of size $N$ is prime is about $\frac{1}{\log N}$, and thus taking $k$ such integers would give you approximately $k / \log N$ primes.

Finally, I'll also note that this heuristic shows that you absolutely cannot hope to get a bound independent of $N$.

Comment: Thank you!! Yeah I see your point.

Comment: Good! If you think this answer has been helpful to you, then it might be nice to upvote it. If you think that this answer completely answers your question, then you can click the check mark next to it to "accept" the answer. These are both signals to later visitors of a question on what answers were helpful or insightful. (Of course if you don't feel like this answer was helpful, or for some other reason don't want to, you do not have to upvote it).